# VueJS development setup without CLI

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am wondering what is a minimal and proper npm project setup for using Vue3 in web development **without Vue CLI**. I used to be using vue2 by directly pulling it in via  tag. But now I want to convert my entire project to be vue based and have a more conventional project setup. What I would like to have are:

- typescript support
- single file component
- I am targeting only the latest Chrome (87+) and Electron so any kind of polyfill is not needed (i think?).

Asking this because when I read through the Vue3 docs at [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html), it says vue-cli is not recommended for beginner.

> The Installation page provides more options of installing Vue. Note: We **do not recommend** that beginners start with vue-cli, especially if you are not yet familiar with Node.js-based build tools.

Comment: If you want single-file-components and Typescript support, your only real option is to use a NodeJS build tool so you might as well go with Vue CLI

Comment: It is fine to use a NodeJS tool chain, but I would still like know what are the different components of such a tool chain instead of going directly with a high level solution such as Vue CLI. After all there will be other dependencies I will need to pull in, and possibly other dev tooling as well.

Comment: Understandable to want to know the components, just be aware that this quoted excerpt is basically telling newbies to start with the CDN.  It's not recommending that those comfortable with a build chain use something other than Vue's CLI.

Comment: [Aymen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11047849) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67078284) saying "I think this Link could answer at your question: [https://github.com/alefi87/vuejs-without-cli](https://github.com/alefi87/vuejs-without-cli)"